# visual studio converted vb to c# by itself?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, vs-extensibility

I was testing a visual studio extension that I wrote in Visual Studio 2022. ALL my code is in vb.net for this project and always has been.

While running it in debug mode, the vs app instance hit a bug, crashed, then took me back to my vs IDE, in which I had the file open that I had changed (call it "MySpecialTools.vb"). Suddenly, a second tab opens in VS, showing me a file named "MySpecialTools.cs" and has highlights where the bug happened. Perplexed, I copied/pasted this file into a text file on my desktop.

As I examined this .cs file, I was surprised to see that it was a copy of "MySpecialTools.vb", but converted into C-Sharp. I checked every folder in my project and could find no instance of this CS file. It appears as though the bug/crash of my running vs add-in, instead of showing me the error in my .vb file, somehow created a CS version of my file!

I've never encountered anything like this, and I know for certain that I did not create the CS file myself. I scrutinized it side-by-side with my .vb code file and it appears to be a complete conversion of that file! The only difference is that it appears that my comments/remarks have been removed along with any line spacing I had made to make my code more readable. It is as though the running executable crashed and the debugger 'decompiled' into the wrong language?

Is this possible?

Comment: VS has [a decompiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2022) that can convert IL in an assembly back to source code.  It is used when it thinks it doesn't have access to the original source.  Only C# is supported, as noted in the linked doc page.  So feature, not a bug, it isn't obvious why it happened from the question.

Comment: Interesting and useful to see, albeit unexpected. I'm guessing that I may have had the original .vb source locked, perhaps open in another viewing app at the time of the exe crash, so the Visual Studio app couldn't see the vb source (as Hans suggests) so it then decompiled as you say.